# Would like to bypass rest of PHP code if submit/cancel is pressed

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a function that can be called in multiple pages which simply writes to $_SESSION['error'] AND error_log and then immediately go back to index.php(skip the rest of the code in file). The function is stored in a common.php file and included at the top of the php file. It executes the function but then continues running the rest of the php code in the main file. Since I am doing some data validation and writting some other stuff to $_SESSSION['error'] its becoming a problem. Is there a was to execute the function and since it has a header call to index.php , not continue the rest of the code? From the code below it executes the 'if' statements after the cpress() function is called and ignores the header function.
Any help would be appreciated.

```php
function cpress() {
  if ( isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    error_log("cpress function debug called");
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Oops, I had to this cancel my last selection!";
    header('Location: index.php') ;}}
```

// called from add.php

```php
cpress();
if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])
     && isset($_POST['email']))  {
```

Would like to load index.php but not do any of the 'if' statements that follow the calling of cpress().

Comment: put return; at the end of the code and it ll work!

Comment: `exit()` after header location always

Comment: @msg they're both the same

Comment: @msg I was understanding your comment was followng Tim's comment above. lol

Comment: I'll try exit, return didnt work since the function is being called from an included script so it just returns back to main script and continues on. Thanks.